# Reopened stdin EOFerror

Tags: c, linux, system

I'm a pwnable newbie and have a question.

this elf close stdout, stdin, stderr before main() function return.

and I reropened them with calling `open("/dev/tty",2)` three times.

stdout is functioning well but when I change EIP to main() and trying to input, this process has EOF error.

So I can't input anything to exploit it.

as far as stdout is work, I leaked libc base and get system() address, "/bin/sh" address in libc.

so I'm trying to restart main and execute system("/bin/sh") with EIP control.

I need to know how to reopen closed stdin with its own performance with functions below.

puts, setbuf, strchr, lseek, close, read, fgets, open, atoi

Help me out!

Comment: If you want to use the original standard streams, then do not close them.  In general, you can open different streams in their places, but you cannot recover the original streams once they are closed.

Comment: Thanks for a comment but it is a condition for this problem...

Comment: You have not presented a problem, just some miscellaneous observations.  If you have a specific problem you are trying to solve then describe that problem clearly, and explain on what specific aspect of it you are stuck.  A [mcve] is probably warranted as part of all that.

Comment: `/dev/fd/` is just a symlink to `/proc/self/fd/`. `/proc/self/fd/N` are pseudosymlinks provided by the kernel that refer to open file descriptor `N` in the process itself. If standard input is already closed, then `/proc/self/fd/0` does not exist. If standard input (or output or error) is open, you can duplicate the descriptor using `dup(0)` (or `dup(1)` or `dup(2)`, respectively). If a process has a controlling terminal, then it can open `/dev/tty` to that terminal. I'd rather see you try to write something useful, instead of attempting to exploit something.

Comment: I editted question.

Comment: You cannot reopen a closed stream. Please quote your assignment verbatim. Your edit hardly improves anything

Comment: @nominalanimal We are not here to judge the usefulness of what the OP is doing.

Comment: @n.m as I writed, I reopened closed stdout and get output from process! but stdin is not.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. The approximate format is like this this. "My assignment says ...(what your assignment says, *literally*, not in your own words, but copy and paste from the assignment). I have done ...(your simplified but still buildable program, *literally*, not a fragment, not a description but actual code). I expect to see ...(what you expect, *literally*, not a description but actual characters you want). But instead I see ...(what you see, *literally*, not a description but copy and paste from the output). Otherwise it is reading the entrails of a chicken.

Comment: @DYZ: We are not here to spout social justice dogma.